# How does windows identify a USB device uniquely?

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, driver, hid

How does windows identify a USB device uniquely, even though the device data supplied from the USB device is common to all devices of that make ? 
To state this alternatively, Windows can distinguish between two instances of Dell keyboards of same model, without the keyboard supplying any unique serial number. What is the exclusive data field windows searches for when initializing the USB device ?

Comment: Is this question specific to devices which don't supply a unique ID? As USB does support unique identifiers for different devices (they aren't required though).

Comment: One instance would be of Keyboard, or HID devices in general do not supply Serial number.

Comment: If the devices are connected to different ports, the host can distinguish them even if they are identical otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Windows uses [Device Instance ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for identification. As you can see in the documentation it contains a device part and an instance part.

The device part is taken from a USB device.

It is up to a bus driver how to generate the instance part. The bus driver cannot solely rely on the information returned from the usb device. Because two identical devices will break the system - Device Instance IDs must be unique! So usually it appends additional info - port number and etc (the exact algorithms is unknown and depends on driver manufacturer). Also PNP manager can add more uniqueness to the Instance ID.

Answer (score 1):

When we connect a device to the host the device, enumeration process will happen, At the end of this process, the host will supply a unique address to the newly connected device. So each device connected to the system will have a unique Id which is supplied by the system, using this id devices can be identified and the communication happens

Comment: Consider this case. The USB device is plugged in for the first time, as long as it powered on the OS knows that particular device. But on restart the device should send some data / unique identifier / unique number field, using which the OS recognises that this device had been plugged in earlier as well.

Comment: @Bleamer if the device was unplugged, it will be reenumerated upon next plugin, regardless of previous state. If device is reset/restarted/whatever you call it, without being plugged out, the enumeration isn't lost and the process of device restart is unrelated to it - it's a proprietary sequence different for each device